# wordpress comment-form-cookies-consent how to checkbox selected?

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

```
cookies' => '<p class="comment-form-cookies-consent"><input id="wp-comment-cookies-consent" name="wp-comment-cookies-consent" type="checkbox" value="yes"' . $consent . ' />' https://www.ozgurbilgi.net
```

checkbox is not selected by default. How do I do this selected? Automatically for visitors. I tried that but it didn't. **checked="checked"**

how can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not `checked ="checked"` its just `checked` as an attribute.  Consider researching your subject a bit more before posting to SO.

[Input Checked Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp#targetText=When%20present%2C%20it%20specifies%20that,page%20load%2C%20with%20a%20JavaScript)

Here are some tips for posting on SO for the future:

- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [Good Questions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- [Debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)